# Пунктирная граница для View через xml в Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

У меня есть простой Layout вида

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="200dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="asdfg"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

В окне предпросмотра (и при запуске) получается такой результат:

[image: окно предпросмотра]

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы по границе `FrameLayout` проходила пунктирная линия. Хочу получить нечто подобное:

[image: пример ожидаемого результата]

Как можно добиться такого результата, не трогая код, а изменяя только `Layout`?

P.s. Текст в центре только для примера, задавать точный размер `FrameLayout` также не буду, это тоже для упрощения примера.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Задание пунктирной границы через `Xml` возможно следующим образом:

1. Создаем в папке `res/drawable` файл `dotted_border.xml`, в поле `Root element` указываем значение `shape`:
   [image: Где создавать файл]
   [image: Меню создания файла]
2. В созданном файле изменяем код на следующий:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

       <stroke
           android:color="#B5B5B5"
           android:dashWidth="10px"
           android:dashGap="10px"
           android:width="1dp"/>
   </shape>
   ```
3. Возвращаемся в исходный `Layout` и задаем свойство `android:background` для `FrameLayout`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="250dp"
       android:layout_height="200dp"
       android:background="@drawable/dotted_border">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:text="asdfg" />

   </FrameLayout>
   ```
4. Наслаждаемся результатом:

   [image: итоговый результат]